# Google Analytics Embed API: Display specific account data, not authenticated users

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

I have this example - [Embed API Third Party Visualizations](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/third-party-visualizations/) - working locally and on a test server, but I'm unsure of what I need to do to ONLY display our organization's Google Analytics data instead of the user's personal GA account.

I created the project and clientID within our org's Google Account, but I'm obviously not understanding something big here.

I'm completely new to both GA's API and oAuth in general, so while I'm sure this has been answered multiple times, I wasn't completely sure which direction to look in.  If someone can give a helpful nudge in the right direction I'll happily be on my way.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Embeded API](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/third-party-visualizations/) uses Oauth2 to authenticate.   Oauth2 requires that a user give you access to `their` Google Analytics data.

You want to show your person Google Analytics data to other users.  Normally I would say you should use a Service account, a service account gives the application direct access to a specific account it has to be set up like you would add a user to Google Analyitcs.   The problem is the Embeded API uses JavaScript, for security reasons its probably not a good idea to use a service account with JavaScript. I also think it may be against Googles terms of service to use a service account with JavaScript.   That being said I have never found anyone who has gotten a service account to work with JavaScript probably for the reasons I just stated.

Drop the embedded API and switch to a server sided language of some kind and code it yourself.    What you want to do cant be done with the embedded API.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!  This makes more sense. I'm going to make your answer as correct and look into using a service account using PHP.